# Chrome Binary file for AWS Lambda

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, selenium, google-chrome, aws-lambda

Can anyone please guide me from where I can download the latest Chrome binary (executable file) for AWS Lambda. I require this for running Selenium in Lambda, and have downloaded chrome driver from here: https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=79.0.3945.36/

Answer (score 1):

You could use `chrome-aws-lambda` to either package chrome with your Lambda or create a `Lambda Layer` (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html) to avoid the package size.

Comment: Thanks Ashish. By chrome-aws-lamba are you referring to this: https://github.com/alixaxel/chrome-aws-lambda? Also can it be used Java?

Comment: It's kind of tricky to find the compatible combination of selenium, chromium, chrome driver version to run in Lambda. 
In NodeJs, a lot of open source packages are available, where we can only focus on developing the Business Logic.